# Почему не меняется значение переменной при нажатии кнопки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

При нажатии кнопки, почему-то значение переменной не изменяется. Не могу понять, в чем ошибка.

```js
$("document").ready(function () {
   
    var v = true;

    //button vegOn

   $("button#vegOn").click(function () {
       if (v == true) {
           v == false;
       } else {
           v == true;
       }

       console.log(v);
   });
   
});//end document Ready
```

```html
<button id="vegOn">Change value</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в условии вы не присваиваете значение, а сравниваете.

Было `v == false;` и `v == true;`, а надо `v = false;` и `v = true;`

```js
$("document").ready(function () {
   
    var v = true;

    //button vegOn

   $("button#vegOn").click(function () {
       if (v == true) {
           v = false;
       } else {
           v = true;
       }

       console.log(v);
   });
   
});//end document Ready
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="vegOn">Change value</button>
```

Comment: Все понял. Спасибо